# Selecting rows according to int and string criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    Capital Social  Mark    Porte
0   12345           B 
1   0               A
2   0               A
3   12345631        A
```

If `Capital Social == 0` and `Mark == A` I want to turn Porte into `Big`. So I'm running the following code:

```
df['Porte'].loc[(df['Capital Social'] == 0) & (df['Mark'] == 'A')]='Big'
```

However, when I run it, the result I get is just the same df:

```
    Capital Social  Mark    Porte
0   12345           B 
1   0               A
2   0               A
3   12345631        A
```

If I `print(df['Capital Social'].dtypes)` I get `Int64` as result.

If I `print(df['Mark'].dtypes)` I get `object` as result. I tried to run `df['Mark']=df['Mark'].astype(str)` but the result keeps being an object. Is this the problem or what am I missing?

Comment: it's a dupe. `df.loc[(df['Capital Social'] == 0) & (df['Mark'] == 'A'), 'Porte']='Big'`

Comment: @MaxU You got a link?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, no, i'm too lazy for that... ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, i tried to correct your level of "mana" ;-)

Comment: @MaxU turns out it was an accidental downvote, haha. Still, thanks, I appreciate the help my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct form is

```
df.loc[(df['Capital Social'] == 0) & (df['Mark'] == 'A'), 'Porte'] = 'Big'
```

`df['Porte']` returns a view/copy, and calling `loc` will modify the copy instead, leaving the original dataFrame untouched.

Answer (score 3):

You are really close:

```
df.loc[(df['Capital Social'] == 0) & (df['Mark'] == 'A'), 'Porte']='Big'
```